# Twig nesting multiple times

Tags: twig

I am trying to work out the correct way to created a Twig component that has sections that are nested 3 deep.

I have a twig file that just creates a header with a class:

**header.twig**

```
<h2>{% block content %}{% endblock %}</h2>
```

and then a twig file that is mid level that consumes that header along with other low level twigs:

**section.twig**

```
<div class="section">
    {% block header %}
        {% embed "components/header.twig" %}
            {% block content %}
                {{ header }}
            {% endblock %}
        {% endembed %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

and then finally, page high level component that consumes the section twig:

**page.twig**

```
<div class="page">
    {{ include("mid/section.twig", { header: fields.header }) }}
</div>
```

Now as you can see in the `section.twig` I'm able to override the block I create but in the highest level `page.twig` I can't override a block twice so I have to use an include instead of an embed.

To me this doesn't feel right and it feels very verbose. To clarify, I am using ACF so that's where `fields.header` comes from and yes I know that the `header.twig` can access that value directly but I am trying to create a structure in which the low and mid level components are "dumb" and the high level component controls the data.

For my given situation, am I going about this the best way that I can or is there another cleaner way that doesn't involve mixing embeds and includes?

Comment: You want to reuse the block header multiple times in one template?

Comment: @DarkBee The block header will be used by mutiple mid level components which will be used by multiple pages as needed.

Comment: Well as included files don't know anything about the blocks inside the template which included them, it seem u'd need to resort to `embed` every time. Perhaps horizontal reuse is something u could use as well, but making this too complex